# Woocommerce Billing City and district not widened

Tags: wordpress, forms, checkout

i have some issues like this.
**2 issues form not widened city and district**

[image: enter image description here[1]]

What can i do for fix this form, cause i'm using checkout field plugin

Regards

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Please check [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do you have a link to your site that you could share?